# <app name> smslogger not defined error

Tags: python, django

I have created a django project named `chart` and app named `smslogger`. I have the app name included in installed app in settings.py and all is fine in django admin.

however i have the url field as
**url**

```
url(r'^new/$', smslogger.views.ChartView.as_view(), name="user_list"),
```

and this complains about `smslogger isnot defined`

the hierarchy of project is

```
chart(project)


         chart
                 urls
smslogger(app)
         views
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

In settings.py

```
from chart.smslogger import views

url(r'^new/$', views.ChartView.as_view(), name="user_list")
```

if ChartView is class, then

```
chart_view = views.ChartView()
url(r'^new/$', chart_view.as_view(), name="user_list")
```